# What is the most efficient way to make Post previews on Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am making a Blog where I want for the home page to show only the first 100 characters of each post.

My point is to make better use of space. If a person want to read a post, that person can just click to read it.

I have some ideas on how to do it, but I think they won`t work or are inefficient:

- To create a subclass on blog models.py where I would inherit the Post class, save the first hundred characters of each content to a list and make a loop to save each list on the database;
- To place a instruction on blog views.py 'FirstPageView' class where it would only exhibit the first hundred characters.

The 'Post' and 'FirstPageView' mentioned classes are as follows:

*on 'blog/views.py':*

```
from django.views.generic import ListView

class FirstPageView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'Blog/home.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']
    paginate_by = 6
```

on 'blog/models.py':

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

So what would be the most efficient way to make those previews?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [built-in template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#truncatechars):

`{{ posts.content|truncatechars:100 }}`